# "error reading characters of string" error after malloc for array of strings

Tags: c

Every time I try to allocate memory for array of strings, my program fails with an error message "error reading characters of strings".
What am I doing wrong? Is there any problem with my memory allocation?

```
char** file2array(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    int i;
    int max_line_len = 20;
    int num_lines = 6;
    char** lines = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (num_lines + 1));

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int chars_num = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    for (i = 1; i < (num_lines + 1); i++) {
        lines[i] = (char *) malloc(max_line_len + 1);
        fgets(lines[i], chars_num, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: The second parameter to `fgets` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have not presented the code that actually emits the error message, so it's hard to be certain what it's complaining about.  You certainly do, however, have a problem with your loop indexing:

```
    for (i = 1; i < (num_lines + 1); i++) {
        lines[i] = /* ... */
```

Variable `i` runs from `1` through `num_lines`, never taking the value `0`, thus the first pointer in your dynamic array of pointers (at index `0`) is never initialized.  That's a plausible explanation for why some later code might have a problem reading the characters.

Additionally, you use `fgets()` wrongly.  You tell it that your buffers are `chars_num` bytes long, but they are actually `max_line_len + 1` bytes long.  This presents the possibility of a buffer overrun.

Indeed, I'm uncertain what the point of `chars_num` is supposed to be.  You initialize it to the length of the file (provided that that length fits in an `int`), but I'm not seeing how that's useful.

Furthermore, your function may return unexpected results if the file being read has lines longer than you account for (20 bytes, including line terminator) or a different number of lines than you expect (6).

I don't see any inherent problem with your memory allocation, but it wouldn't be StackOverflow if I didn't give you a severe tongue-lashing for casting the return value of `malloc()`.  Consider yourself flogged.